# Crear una tabla MySQL a partir de columnas de dataframe en google cloud

Tags: python, mysql, mongodb, google-cloud-storage, pipeline

Tengo una lista de documentos en una base de datos MongoDB y me gustaría extraer constantemente partes de cada uno que no estén ya en la base de datos en una tabla MySQL alojada en CloudSQL para preparar un algoritmo de recomendación de productos. Es decir, quiero transformar todos los datos de la siguiente consulta en MongoDB:

```
>>> all_perfumes = list(collection.aggregate([
    {"$project": {"d": 1}}
]))
```

Como esto:

```
>>> all_perfumes =[0]
{'_id': ObjectId('5fd5e617260828c7646000aa'), 'd': {'attributs': {'Doux': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'DÃ©licat': {'claimed_benefit':
 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'Elegant': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'Mature': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'Se
xy': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'FÃ©minin': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'Frais': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perce
ived_benefit': 0.35294117647058826}, 'Classe': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'Mou': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, '
DÃ©contractÃ©': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'Comme les autres': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'Jeune femme': {'cl
aimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'charmant': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'Gai': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefi
t': 0.058823529411764705}, 'Propre': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.058823529411764705}, 'EtÃ©': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit':
 0.0}, 'RafraÃ®chissant': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'Chaud': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'Masculin': {'claime
d_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.23529411764705882}, 'Fiable': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'MystÃ©rieux': {'claimed_benefit': 0,
 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'Furtif': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.058823529411764705}, 'Fort': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit'
: 0.4117647058823529}, 'Hivernal': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'HerbacÃ©': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'Plantes
': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'Big brands': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.058823529411764705}, 'Luxueux': {'claimed_
benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.0}, 'Connu': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'perceived_benefit': 0.23529411764705882}, 'A la mode': {'claimed_benefit': 0, 'per
ceived_benefit': 0.0}}}}
```

tomando la media de cada `atributo` e ingiriendo cada resultado a una tabla MySQL en CloudSQL. Sin embargo, todavía no he creado esta tabla. Así que pensé en hacer esto desde el Cloud Shell:

```
import datetime

import pandas as pd
import pytz
import pymongo

import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


### CREATING DATAFRAME ###
mongo_client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.n2hnd.mongodb.net/ifresearch?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
collection = mongo_client.test.sephora_backup3

all_perfumes = list(collection.aggregate([
            {"$project": {"d": 1}}
        ]))

# Necesito filtrar los perfumes que ya estan en la Base de Datos MySQL
# o los que no han sido modificados
rows_list = []
for perfume in all_perfumes:
    for attribute in perfume['d']['attributs'].items():
        up_dict = {attribute[0]: sum(attribute[1].values())}
        perfume['d']['attributs'].update(up_dict)
    rows_list.append(perfume['d']['attributs'])
df = pd.DataFrame(rows_list)


db = 'scentmate'
db_tbl_name = 'scores'


'''
Create a mapping of df dtypes to mysql data types (not perfect, but close enough)
'''
def dtype_mapping():
    return {'object' : 'TEXT',
        'int64' : 'INT',
        'float64' : 'FLOAT',
        'datetime64' : 'DATETIME',
        'bool' : 'TINYINT',
        'category' : 'TEXT',
        'timedelta[ns]' : 'TEXT'}
'''
Create a sqlalchemy engine
'''
def mysql_engine(user = 'root', password = '', host = '0.1.2.3', port = '???', database = 'scentmate'):
    engine = create_engine("mysql://{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}/{4}?charset=utf8".format(user, password, host, port, database))
    return engine

'''
Create a mysql connection from sqlalchemy engine
'''
def mysql_conn(engine):
    conn = engine.raw_connection()
    return conn
'''
Create sql input for table names and types
'''
def gen_tbl_cols_sql(df):
    dmap = dtype_mapping()
    sql = "pi_db_uid INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY"
    df1 = df.rename(columns = {"" : "nocolname"})
    hdrs = df1.dtypes.index
    hdrs_list = [(hdr, str(df1[hdr].dtype)) for hdr in hdrs]
    for i, hl in enumerate(hdrs_list):
        sql += " ,{0} {1}".format(hl[0], dmap[hl[1]])
    return sql

'''
Create a mysql table from a df
'''
def create_mysql_tbl_schema(df, conn, db, tbl_name):
    tbl_cols_sql = gen_tbl_cols_sql(df)
    sql = "USE {0}; CREATE TABLE {1} ({2})".format(db, tbl_name, tbl_cols_sql)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql)
    cur.close()
    conn.commit()

'''
Write df data to newly create mysql table
'''
def df_to_mysql(df, engine, tbl_name):
    df.to_sql(tbl_name, engine, if_exists='replace')

create_mysql_tbl_schema(df, mysql_conn(mysql_engine()), db, db_tbl_name)
df_to_mysql(df, mysql_engine(), db_tbl_name)
```

Pero obtengo:

```
(etl_env) mikempc3@cloudshell:~$ python3 et_scores.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mikempc3/etl_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3212, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "/home/mikempc3/etl_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 301, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/home/mikempc3/etl_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 761, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/home/mikempc3/etl_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 419, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/home/mikempc3/etl_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 145, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "/home/mikempc3/etl_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 72, in __exit__
    with_traceback=exc_tb,
  File "/home/mikempc3/etl_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 211, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/mikempc3/etl_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 142, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/home/mikempc3/etl_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 247, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/home/mikempc3/etl_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 362, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "/home/mikempc3/etl_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 605, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "/home/mikempc3/etl_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 72, in __exit__
    with_traceback=exc_tb,
  File "/home/mikempc3/etl_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 211, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/mikempc3/etl_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 599, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/home/mikempc3/etl_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 578, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/home/mikempc3/etl_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 584, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/home/mikempc3/etl_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 130, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mikempc3/etl_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 185, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '35.240.96.173' (110)")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "et_scores.py", line 103, in <module>
    create_mysql_tbl_schema(df, mysql_conn(mysql_engine()), db, db_tbl_name)
  File "et_scores.py", line 71, in mysql_conn
    conn = engine.raw_connection()
  File "/home/mikempc3/etl_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3245, in raw_connection
    return self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, _connection)
  File "/home/mikempc3/etl_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3216, in _wrap_pool_connect
    e, dialect, self
  File "/home/mikempc3/etl_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2069, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
  File "/home/mikempc3/etl_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 211, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/mikempc3/etl_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3212, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "/home/mikempc3/etl_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 301, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/home/mikempc3/etl_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 761, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/home/mikempc3/etl_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 419, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/home/mikempc3/etl_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 145, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "/home/mikempc3/etl_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 72, in __exit__
    with_traceback=exc_tb,
  File "/home/mikempc3/etl_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 211, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/mikempc3/etl_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 142, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/home/mikempc3/etl_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 247, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/home/mikempc3/etl_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 362, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "/home/mikempc3/etl_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 605, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "/home/mikempc3/etl_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 72, in __exit__
    with_traceback=exc_tb,
  File "/home/mikempc3/etl_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 211, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/mikempc3/etl_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 599, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/home/mikempc3/etl_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 578, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/home/mikempc3/etl_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 584, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/home/mikempc3/etl_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 130, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mikempc3/etl_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 185, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '35.240.96.173' (110)")
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
(etl_env) mikempc3@cloudshell:~$
```

Comment: Recuerda que MongoDB es una BD no rrlacional, así que tendrás que hacer un modelo ara transformar o reagrupar tus datos para pasarlos a MySQL

Comment: Sí eso, lo tengo controlado @Christian a priori los atributos serán siempre los mismos. Esto me permite preparar el schema del base de datos.